# Non - Monotonic Random Variable Transformation

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with pdf $f_X(x)$ and standing $S=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\::\: f_X(x)>0\}$ and let $Y=g(X)$ be a transformation. Should $g$ be a non-monotonic function, how could I find the pdf of $Y$? Can someone point me to any books that explain transformations of variables in depth?

Edit: I meant that $g$ is monotonic at separate intervals of it's domain.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/478109/2921